# A specific MP4 file is not playable with avfoundation in iOS

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ios

I have an mp4 video file that I want to play it in iOS using avfoundation. Unfortunately, the file is not being played and save into the default gallery (photos) even it has **h264** video codec and **aac** audio codec. And it is only playable when I reencode it using ffmpeg. I want to know why the file only becomes playable after reencoding the video?

### Not Playable(originalFile.mp4) vs Playable File(outputFile.mp4) Information Comparison

[image]

**File is playable with avfoundation when these commands are being applied:**

1. `ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i originalFile.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec h264 -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -b:v 5703k -acodec aac -b:a 249k outputFile.mp4`
2. `ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i originalFile.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac outputFile.mp4`

**File is not playable with avfoundation when this command is being applied:**

1. `ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i originalFile.mp4 -f mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec aac outputFile.mp4`

**originalFile.mp4 file link:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-yZFL0EsLztMIfwU79Al6dv8gdwJyGAD/view?usp=sharing

**ffprobe streams of both files are here**
https://www.diffchecker.com/VgZL66QB

Comment: **NOTE: I can't comment to Jason Conrad so I am posting it as an answer and will delete it.** How do we understand if a video is interlaced from the information FFMPEG provides us? In the above answer Jason Conrad mentions that "smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709." means its interlaced video. But this is just color space information. How does it mean interlace or progressive? Is it possible to share anymore details or URL to read further? Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: Share the full output of `ffprobe -show_streams` for both original file and outputfile.

Comment: @Gyan I've modified the question and now you can get the outputs of ffprobe streams  from there. Thanks.

Comment: Only the colorimetry appears to be different. But that shouldn't stop playback. Nevertheless, try `ffmpeg -i originalFile.mp4 -c copy -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -movflags +faststart outputFile.mp4`

Comment: @Gyan I've applied your suggested command but nothing has changed in the outputFile's information and the video isn't playable on iOS either. Can you suggest any special reads on colorimetry, please?
Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using 4.2.1, also add `-write_colr 1` and check.

Comment: @Gyan I've applied this command 

`ffmpeg -i originalFile.mp4 -c copy -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -movflags write_colr outputFile.mp4` and still there is no difference between originalFile.mp4 and outputFile.mp4 information. Is it the appropriate command that you suggested to apply?

Comment: @Gyan I've included originalFile.mp4 link in the question which file is not playable via iOS default video player or Avfoundation. Thanks.

Comment: Link not accessible

Comment: @Gyan The link should be accessible now.

Comment: The H.264 video stream is stored using MBAFF coding, which is likely not supported in AVFoundation. You'll have to re-encode.

Comment: @Gyan How can we ensure that the video stream is stored using MBAFF coding? Thank you.

Comment: How is original file generated?

Comment: Basically, we've got this file from one of our users!

Answer (score 1):

The original video is an old, interlaced format.  At least, according to the line that says, "smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709."  The SMPTE standard is available for purchase [here](https://standards.globalspec.com/std/892300/SMPTE%20ST%20170M), but you can tell from the summary that it's interlaced.

The second ffmpeg command is copying the format without re-encoding, or handling the interlacing, which isn’t supported on iOS.  The first set of commands work because the video is being re-encoded. Whether or not the video is automatically being de-interlaced, I can’t say without seeing, but I doubt it.  See my answer to [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/how-to-see-if-a-video-file-is-progressive-or-interlaced/12982#12982) to judge for yourself.

Comment: `smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709` only indicates colorimetry and nothing about scan.

Comment: The incompatibility  -- regardless of its nature -- is present in the original file.  The blue highlighting in the "Information Comparison" graphic illustrates the only differences between the files of which we know.  Of those differences, only the SMPTE spec is salient.  Sure, it's an educated guess, but there's really not much else to go on.

Comment: The first string `smpte170m` refers to the colorspace, the 2nd `bt470bg` refers to the color primaries and the 3rd `bt709` to the transfer function (gamma). Interlacing, when detected, will be indicated by printing of the field order e.g. `top first`, after colorimetry.

Comment: So you're saying the original file follows the smpte170m color standard, but isn't interlaced.  I accept that.  But still, whatever incompatibility exists, is in the original file, which is why the -copy argument produces an incompatible file, and why re-encoding doesn't.